# Matlab isn't incrementing my variable

Tags: matlab, debugging, matrix, max

I have the following matrix declared in Matlab:

```
EmployeeData =
           1          20      100000          42          14
           2          15       95000          35          14
           3          18       70000          28          14
           4          10       85000          35          14
           5          10       40000          21          12
           6           4       45000          14           8
           7           3       50000          21          10
           8           5       55000          21          14
           9           1       25000          14           7
          10           2       50000          21           9
          42           4      100000          42          10
```

Where column 1 represents ID numbers, 2 represents years, 3 is salary, 4 is vacation days, and 5 is sick days.  I am trying to find the maximum value of a column (in this case the salary column), and print out the ID associated with that value.  If more than one employee has the maximum value, all the IDs with that maximum are supposed to be shown.  So here is how I naively implemented a way to do it:

```
>> maxVal = [];
>> j = 1;
>> for i = EmployeeData(:, 3)
      if i == max(EmployeeData(:, 3))
          maxVal = [maxVal EmployeeData(j, 1)];
      end
      j = j + 1;
   end
```

But it shows `maxVal` to be `[]` in my workspace variables, instead of `[1 42]` as I expected.  Upon inserting a `disp(i)` in the `for` loop above the `if` to debug, I get the following output:

```
  100000
   95000
   70000
   85000
   40000
   45000
   50000
   55000
   25000
   50000
```

Just like I expected.  But when I switch out that `disp(i)` with a `disp(j)`, I get this for my output:

```
  1
```

What am I doing wrong?  Should this not work?

Comment: your for loop only executed once with i been all those values, then come down to j. the (:,3) will not run every row value but column value once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB for loops operate on rows, not columns. You should try replacing your for loop with:

```
for i = EmployeeData(:, 3)' % NOTE THE TRANSPOSE
    ...
end
```

EDIT: Note that you can do what you're trying to do without a forloop:

```
maxVal = EmployeeData(EmployeeData(:,3) == max(EmployeeData(:,3)),1);
```

Comment: Yes it does. If you run a for loop on a column, MATLAB will run through the for loop once. If you run it on a row, it will run through each value in the row. Have you even tried it?

Comment: @syb0rg to support MrAzzaman's statement, read in http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/for.html when *index* is a *valArray*

Comment: I have to add, I programmed in Matlab for many years and I tend to avoid this style like the plague. I would either fully vectorize as you showed below, or take a for loop over the indices rather than the actual values. Slices in Matlab are by value (I'm pretty sure), so if you modify your code at some point in the future to modify the original matrix, it will modify a copy, leading to a potentially hard to detect bug.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
>> EmployeeData(EmployeeData(:,3)==max(EmployeeData(:,3)),1)
ans =
     1
    42
```